# How to trigger a function when date change?

Tags: python, python-3.x, triggers, tinydb

I want to split my `TinyDB` JSONs to be one per day.
I wonder if there is some function to trigger a function call once the day is changed and return to the same spot it was in the code. There is only `db.insert` in the code so I might want to lock/serialize that part..

For example every day at 00:00:00 time the following function will get called:

```
change_db():
  db = TinyDB('/stream_' + datetime.date.today() + '.json')
```

Comment: You probably wouldn’t want your database to change asynchronously at whatever time—just call that function periodically to update the database as needed.

Comment: I just think it is kind old to check every `x` if the day had changed.. Therefor trigger or listener can be useful.

Comment: Even with another thread or so sleeping until the right time, you have to have some sort of synchronization with the main processing that needs to know when it changes.  Checking the clock instead of a flag is not particularly expensive (if done rarely enough), and it keeps the structure of the code simpler.  Things would be different if the main work was just waiting rather than using resources continuously.

Comment: Since I have only one thread that handle inserts into the db using mutex is the way I was thinking to achieve it.